# Remove target inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, target

I have a website inside an iframe, and the links inside the external document do have a target="_top" attribute. So if I click one of them, the whole page "jumps" out of my iframe.
Is there a way to remove them, without touching the external site?

I thought about something like

```
$('a[target="_top"]').removeAttr('target');
```

but it doesn't change anything inside the iframe (and I would be happy, if I could avoid using jQuery).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to use JavaScript to change content on a third party site you're hosting inside an iframe? If so, you're not going to have much luck.

Comment: The only thing close to what you're asking is the sandbox attribute of an iframe which at the moment isn't supported by all browsers

Comment: I'm doing this for a fair, the normal Website will show up with extra Navigation at the top. So I won't touch the original code, as it would screw up the original (not worth for a 4 day fair)...

Comment: Browser support isn't a problem, it should work on just one pc, which i could setup like I need

Answer (score 2):

In light of the fact that browser compatibility isn't an issue...

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms"></iframe>
```

... Will stop the iframe from navigating the parent document.

Actual information on browser support can be found here...
http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox

Comment: I like the idea, but if I try this, i can't open the links anymore - they react like plain text. Could be an issue from the original site...
Thanks for your hint!